# Delay while using operations in different views

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, afnetworking

I am working on a medical app that explains about some medical terms and its details.I have to handle the several operations to download the images and some audio files. I have two classes to handle the networking operations and cache operations for image downloading and audio downloading respectively. I have used AFNetworking to handle all the operations and i am using Swift. The scenario is on application launch , i am calling the func of image class to download all images and on respective viewcontroller to view the term detail, i have an option to play the audio file if available. However if i hit the play button, the audio is downloaded only after all the images(eg: 20 images) are downloaded that was handled from the application delegate.

```
 import UIKit

let ImageFileDirectory : String = "Image-cache"

typealias ImageDownloadCallBackSuccess = ( String , UIImage) -> Void

class ImageManager: NSObject {    

override init() {
    super.init()
}



func downloadImageFile (imageData : Dictionary<String,AnyObject>, callback: ImageDownloadCallBackSuccess) -> Void {

    let imageUrl : NSString = (imageData as NSDictionary).objectForKey("url") as! NSString

    let imageId : Int = (imageData as NSDictionary).objectForKey("id") as! Int

    let imageIDString : String = String(imageId)

    let filemanager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if !filemanager.fileExistsAtPath(filePath(imageIDString)) {


        var opManager : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        opManager.responseSerializer = AFImageResponseSerializer()
        opManager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 180.0

        let newOperation = opManager.HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest( NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: imageUrl)!), success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in
            println("File Saved to ImageCacheDirectory")

            let imageData : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(responseObject as! UIImage, 1.0)
            imageData.writeToFile(self.filePath(imageIDString), atomically: true)

            callback(imageIDString, responseObject as! UIImage)

            }, failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                println("Couldn't save the file to ImageCacheDirectory")

        })
        newOperation.start()

    }
    else {

        println("file exist for path")
    }
}

class func filePathForImage (imageID: String) -> (String!) {

    let documentsPath : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask,true)[0] as! String

    let fileExtensionString = String(format:"/%@/", ImageFileDirectory)
    let folderPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(fileExtensionString)")
    let filemanager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    var err: NSErrorPointer = nil

    if !filemanager.fileExistsAtPath(folderPath) {

        filemanager.createDirectoryAtPath(folderPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: err)
    }

    var filePath = "\(folderPath)"
    filePath += "/"
    filePath += "\(imageID)"
    filePath += "."
    filePath += "jpg"

    return filePath
}


func imageRootDirectory() -> String {

    let documentsPath : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask,true)[0] as! String

    let imageDirectory = String(format:"/%@/", ImageFileDirectory)

    return documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(imageDirectory)")
}
func filePath (imageID :String) -> String {

    let folderPath = imageRootDirectory()

    var filePath = "\(folderPath)"
    filePath += "/"
    filePath += "\(imageID)"
    filePath += "."
    filePath += "jpg"

    return filePath

}

func downloadAllImage () {

    for imageObject  in DataManager.sharedInstance.allImages {

        downloadImageFile(imageObject, callback: { (imageString, imageData) -> Void in
        })
    }
}
}



typealias AudioDownloadHandler = (Double) -> Void

let AudioFileDirectory : String = "Audio-cache"

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class AudioManager: NSObject ,AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

var audioID : Int?
var audioUrl : String?

var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer! // will be Optional, must supply initializer

override init() {

    super.init()

}

init (audioId : Int , audioUrl: String) {
    self.audioUrl = audioUrl
    self.audioID = audioId
    super.init()

}

func cacheAudioFile(callback:AudioDownloadHandler) -> Void {

    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: self.audioUrl!)!)
    let audioDownloadOperation: AFHTTPRequestOperation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: request)
    audioDownloadOperation.outputStream = NSOutputStream(toFileAtPath: filePathForAudio()!, append: false)

    audioDownloadOperation.setDownloadProgressBlock({(bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead) -> Void in

        var total: CGFloat = CGFloat(totalBytesRead) / CGFloat(totalBytesExpectedToRead)
        callback(Double(total))
    })
    audioDownloadOperation.start()

}

func filePathForAudio () -> (String!) {

    let documentsPath : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask,true)[0] as! String

    let fileExtensionString = String(format:"/%@/", AudioFileDirectory)
    let folderPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(fileExtensionString)")
    let filemanager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    var err: NSErrorPointer = nil

    if !filemanager.fileExistsAtPath(folderPath) {

        filemanager.createDirectoryAtPath(folderPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: err)
    }

    var filePath = "\(folderPath)"
    filePath += "/"
    filePath += "\(self.audioID!)"
    filePath += "."
    filePath += "\(self.audioUrl!.pathExtension)"
    return filePath
}

func playAudioFile () {

    var filePathUrl : NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePathForAudio())!
    var error: NSError!
    self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: nil)
    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self

    if let player : AVAudioPlayer = self.audioPlayer as AVAudioPlayer?{
        self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()

    }
}

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer!, successfully flag: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("AudioFinishedPlaying", object: nil)
}
}

            let imageManager = ImageManager()
            imageManager.downloadAllImage ()
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @DuncanC Is there any problem with the operation management with my code.

Comment: Unrelated, but I would not advise using `AFImageResponseSerializer` and then using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to re-create `NSData` that (a)  likely makes it larger; and (b) possibly loses meta data in the process. You might be able to get original `NSData` by looking at the operation's `responseData` property. Or use standard `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` and then convert that to `UIImage` yourself. Either way, save the original response data, not re-extracting it from image.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a bunch of image download operations and then want to create one video download operation that you don't want backlogged being the image downloads, there are a couple of considerations to keep in mind:

- Using `NSURLConnection`, you are constrained by how many requests will actually be performed concurrently (5, I believe).
- You are manually calling `start` to the operations. Thus, you are taking advantage of neither (a) the ability to constrain how many concurrent operations are running; nor (b) the priority, dependencies, nor quality of service of the individual operations.

The basic idea is to use operation queues and operation properties to dictate the behaviors associated with when operations run.

I would therefore suggest that you don't call `start` anymore and rather add the operations to queues of your creation. You can either create an image download queue (with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of something like 3) and a separate video download queue. Your `NSURLConnection` will therefore not be running more than 3 image download requests at a time, and thus you have the capacity to run a video download concurrently, not waiting for the image downloads.

The other approach is to have a single generic download queue, perhaps use a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 4 or 5, and when you create the image and video downloads, give the video operation a higher priority/QoS.